# Fazer um array para uma query com condições falsas

Tags: php, wordpress, query

Tenho a seguinte `query`, onde as condições são informadas a partir de um `array`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'post',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'orderby'             => 'date',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'category_name'       => $atts['category_name'],
    'posts_per_page'      => ($atts['number'] > 0) ? $atts['number'] : 
                              get_option('posts_per_page')
 );

 $meta_query[] = array(
    'key'   => '_featured',
    'value' => 'yes' 
 );

 $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;

 $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Essa `query` me traz os `posts` que são marcados como `Featured`.
Porém o que eu preciso é o inverso, preciso dos `posts` que não são `Featured`.
Se eu colocar somente `'no'` no lugar do `'yes'`, nesse trecho:

```
'key'   => '_featured',
'value' => 'yes'
```

Ele somente me retorna os `posts` que um dia já foram `featured`. Porém aqueles que nunca foram, não aparecem, porque esses nem possuem a `meta_key featured`.

O mais fácil a meu ver seria trazer os `posts` diferentes de `"featured = yes"`, mas eu não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: E se você deixar o `'Value' => ''` ??

Comment: Ou algo assim:  `$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'   => '_featured',
    'key.count' => 0,
    'value' => 'no' 
  );`

Comment: se eu deixar assim:  'Value' => '' não retorna nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além dos elementos `key` e `value`, a `meta_query` suporta o operador de comparação no elemento `compare`. Tente `!=`:

```
 $meta_query[] = array(
    'key'     => '_featured',
    'value'   => 'yes' ,
    'compare' => '!='
  );
```

Há bastante informação sobre isso no [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), e encontrei um tutorial mais "mastigado" [aqui](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-custom-fields--cms-23091). Uma busca por "meta_compare" mostra que os valores possíveis são os suportados pelo MySQL:

`'='`, `'!='`, `'>'`, `'>='`, `'<'`, `'<='`, `'LIKE'`, `'NOT LIKE'`, `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, `'BETWEEN'`, `'NOT BETWEEN'`, `'NOT EXISTS'`, `'REGEXP'`, `'NOT REGEXP'` or `'RLIKE'`

Sendo que o padrão é o operador de igualdade `'='`.

Para mais informações sobre a utilidade de cada operador, a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html) é bem detalhada.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigada pessoal, foi de muita ajuda!

O código que funcionou foi o seguinte:

```
$meta_query[] = array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
   array (
         'key'   => '_featured',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
         ),
   array (
         'key'   => '_featured',
         'value' => 'no' 
         )  
);
```

Comment: Não fica ambíguo assim Nathalia? Não da pra colocar o `'value' => 'no'` dentro do primeiro` array` ?

Comment: Não fica, porque são 2 tipos de posts. Existem os posts que possuem a _feature = no (esses um dia já foram "yes") e existem os posts q não possuem o parâmetro _feature.

Comment: Sim, tudo bem, é que esses `arrays` aí são para que o `Wordpress` monte o `SQL`, então como a consulta vai ser uma só, acredito que vai dar no mesmo se você colocar dentro de um array somente, não ?

Comment: Pelo que eu li no tutorial postado pelo nunks.lol [aqui](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-custom-fields--cms-23091), são necessários os 2 arrays para poder adicionar o OR.

Comment: Ahh sim, não tinha visto o relacionamento ali, aí sim faz sentido. Falha minha ’＝D